# Select last record out of grouped records

Tags: sql

i have this code and i want someone to help me to change it to a grouped query which orders froms below.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.users_pics INNER JOIN profile 
    ON users_pics.email = profile.email 
        Left  Join photo_comment 
        On users_pics.u_pic_id = photo_comment.pic_id
WHERE users_pics.wardrobe = MMColParam
ORDER BY u_pic_id asc
```

what i mean is i have grouped of records which i want to select one per record only from beneath. for example if i have 10 records of the name "John" i want to select the last "John" out of the 10 and then the rest also follows

Comment: Can you provide some sample data

Comment: Also please let us know which RDBMS you're using...MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server?

Comment: What is the sub-order column on which get the last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to presume that your `users` table contains a single user, and each user has a single profile, and your `photo_comment` table can contain multiple comments.

Depending on your `RDBMS`, you can do this a number of ways.  `Row_Number` can often be a quick way of doing this if you're using a database which supports window functions such as SQL Server or Oracle.

A generic solution to this is to join the table back to itself using the `MAX` aggregate.  This is dependent on having a field to determine which record is the max.  Generally speaking, that would be an identity/auto number field or a time stamp field.

Here is the basic concept using `photo_comment_id` as your determining column:

```
SELECT *  
FROM dbo.users_pics INNER JOIN profile 
    ON users_pics.email = profile.email 
        LEFT Join (
            SELECT pic_id, MAX(photo_comment_id) max_photo_comment_id
            FROM max_photo_comment 
            GROUP BY pic_id
        ) max_photo_comment On users_pics.u_pic_id = max_photo_comment.pic_id
        LEFT Join photo_comment On 
            max_photo_comment.pic_id = photo_comment.pic_id AND
            max_photo_comment.max_photo_comment_id = photo_comment.photo_comment_id
WHERE users_pics.wardrobe = MMColParam
ORDER BY u_pic_id asc
```

---

If your database supports `ROW_NUMBER`, then you can do this as well (still using the `photo_comment_id` field):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY photo_comment.pic_id 
                           ORDER BY photo_comment.photo_comment_id DESC) rn 
    FROM dbo.users_pics INNER JOIN profile 
        ON users_pics.email = profile.email 
            LEFT JOIN photo_comment 
                ON users_pics.u_pic_id = photo_comment.pic_id
    WHERE users_pics.wardrobe = MMColParam
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY u_pic_id asc
```

Comment: when i execute it tells me ROW NUMBER is not a recognize function name. i use microsoft sql server

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` was introduced in SQL Server 2005 and higher.  What version are you using?  See this fiddle for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/648f2/1

Comment: i just change from sql server 2000 to 2005 and when i execute it tell me incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. please i new to sql so if you could please help me

Comment: @user3060221 -- try adding a table alias to the subquery -- looks like I left that off.  `SELECT * FROM (...) t WHERE rn = 1` ...

Comment: @user3060221 -- or try the first solution.  It doesn't matter what DB you are using for it, it should work.

Comment: thanks #sgeddes for the good work, how will i rewrite the whole code i want to count too the total number of fields of the column "comment" in table photo_comment